# Python - Sorting file highest to lowest and alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, math, testing

I have created an arithmetic code, that asks the user 10 questions, and then stores their name and score in a database e.g. `C:\class1.txt` and I'm now at the stage, where I should be able to sort the file containing the name and the score of multiple pupils from each individual class, in both highest to lowest (scores) and alphabetically. The program should ask a question at the end of the code, asking the teacher if they want it sorted alphabetically or highest to lowest by score. They should also be able to pick the class they want sorted, and it should be printed.

I am asking for guidance on this, I do not want to cheat, I am just now clueless at this stage; with a teacher that is useless.

Thanks in advance

```py
import random
USER_SCORE = 0
questions = 0
classnumber = ("1","2","3")
name1= input("Enter Your Username: ")
print("Hello, " + name1)
print(" Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz")

classno = input("What class are you in?")
while classno not in classnumber:
    print("Enter a valid class")
    print("ENTER ONLY THE NUMBER n\ 1 n\ 2 n\3")
    classno=input("What class are you in?")

while questions <10:
    for i in range(10):
        num1=random.randint(1,10)
        num2=random.randint(1,10)
        on=random.choice("*-+")
        multiply=num1*num2
        subtract=num1-num2
        addition=num1+num2

        if on == "-": #If "-" or subtract is randomly picked.
            print("MAKE SURE YOU ENTER A NUMBER OTHERWISE YOU WILL BE MARKED DOWN")
            questions+=1
            print(" Question" ,questions, "/10")
            uinput=input(str(num1)+" - "+str(num2))
            if uinput == str(subtract):
                USER_SCORE+=1
                print("     Correct, your USER_SCORE is: " ,USER_SCORE,)
            else:
                print ("    Incorrect, the answer is: " +str(subtract))
                USER_SCORE+=0

        if on == "+":
            print("MAKE SURE YOU ENTER A NUMBER OTHERWISE YOU WILL BE MARKED DOWN")
            questions+=1
            print(" Question",questions, "/10")
            uinput=input(str(num1)+" + "+str(num2))
            if uinput == str(addition):
                USER_SCORE+=1
                print("  Correct, your USER_SCORE is: ",USER_SCORE,)
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " +str(addition))
                USER_SCORE+=0

        if on == "*":
            print("MAKE SURE YOU ENTER A NUMBER OTHERWISE YOU WILL BE MARKED DOWN")
            questions+=1
            print(" Question",questions, "/10")
            uinput=input(str(num1)+" * "+str(num2))
            if uinput == str(multiply):
                USER_SCORE+=1
                print("  Correct, your USER_SCORE is: " ,USER_SCORE,)
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " +str(multiply))
                USER_SCORE+=0

if USER_SCORE >9:
    print("Well done," ,name1, "your score is" ,USER_SCORE, "/10")
else:
 print(name1," your score is " ,USER_SCORE, "/10")

def no1():
     with open("no1.txt", 'a')as file:
         file.write(str(name1)+" achieved a score of:  "+str(USER_SCORE)+"/10 \n")
def no2():
     with open("no2.txt", 'a')as file:
         file.write(str(name1)+" achieved a score of "+str(USER_SCORE)+"/10 \n")
def no3():
     with open("no3.txt", 'a')as file:
         file.write(str(name1)+" achieved a score of "+str(USER_SCORE)+"/10 \n")
if classno=="1":
    no1()
if classno=="2":
    no2()
if classno=="3":
    no3()
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you want to solve? What does your code do now, and what do you want to change?

Comment: The code is a working code, there are no problems with this code, however, I need to add something, there is a task in which we must give the teacher an option to sort the code alphabetically or highest to lowest, now the code askes 10 questions, for a name, and a class, and prints all the above in a file depending on the class chosen

Comment: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* What did you do until now to implement your new function? How do you think you will do to sort data? Did you wrote down on paper a rough design of the steps you need?...

Comment: Try using a loop to go through each score/user, adding it into a list like so `your_list.append(line)`, then calling `new_list = sort(your_list)`, then writing the file from the sorted list. After that you'll be able to try sorting it different ways. Try simplifying your questions/problems to smaller components like "How do I read lines from a file?" "How do I sort a list alphabetically?" Those sorts of questions have been asked many times on SO, and you can piece them together for your project.

Comment: crclayton, can you please expand? looping using while ? please can you give and example, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @crclayton forgot to add it

Comment: @crclayton sorry to bother you, but please look at the answer I gave, ? I know how to alphabetically sort it I think, but I still don't know how to sort from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, in order to code you need to be able to break your problem into smaller components. Each of those smaller problems should be their own function. It'll be easier to keep track of things and solve smaller problems.

Here are some examples of the sort of functions you should make. I can't stress enough that your questions on S.O. should be about those individual problems, not wanting to know generally how to do things.

Try to fill in the blanks of this structure.

```
import random

def get_score():
    # here do your code to calculate the score
    score = random.randint(0,10)
    return score

def write_list_to_file():
    # for each item in list, write that to a file 
    pass

def sort_list_alphabetically(unsorted_list):
    # figure out how to sort a list one way
    return sorted_list

def sort_list_numerically(unsorted_list):
    # figure out how to sort a list the other way
    return sorted_list

def get_sort_method_from_user():
    # get input however you want
    if soandso:
        return "Alphabetical"
    else:
        return "Numerical"

def get_user_name():
    # do your stuff
    return name;


questions = 0
list_of_scores = []

while questions < 10:

    name = get_user_name();
    user_score = get_score();

    output_line = name + " got a score of " + user_score

    list_of_scores.append(output_line)


sort_method = get_sort_method_from_user();

if sort_method == "Alphabetical":
    new_list = sort_list_alphabetically(list_of_scores)
else:
    new_list = sort_list_numerically(list_of_scores)

write_list_to_file(list_of_scores)
```

Answer (score 2):

@crclayton

I found this for alphabetical sorting, however, I still don't know how to sort the file from highest to lowest

viewclass= input("choose a class number and either alphabetically, average or highest?")

```
    if viewclass=='1 alphabetically':
        with open('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
            for line in sorted(r):
                 print(line, end='')


    elif viewclass=='2 alphabetically':
        with open('class2.txt', 'r') as r:
            for line in sorted(r):
                 print(line, end='')

    elif viewclass=='3 alphabetically':
        with open('class3.txt', 'r') as r:
            for line in sorted(r):
                 print(line, end='')
```